# Why is my script failing on the if conditional?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Hi I have this if statement which im using to try and validate if an element exists on the page(it can exist and sometimes it cannot exist in specific scenarios)

the script fails on the line with the if statement condition(when element is not displayed because it doesnt exist)

```
  public void checker()
        {
           WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));           
           openDocDrawer();

           if (isDisplayed(rowsWithinDrawer))
           {
               documentDrawerCloser();
               wait.Until(driver => docDrawerButton.Displayed);
               Console.Writeline("is displayed")
           }                                
           else 
           {
               reviewStageCreatorTimeSpan();
               documentDrawerCloser();
               wait.Until(driver => docDrawerButton.Displayed);
               Console.Writeline("is displayed")

           }
          
        }
```

here is the stack trace

```
  Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"mat-row"}
      (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
  Stack Trace: 
    RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
    RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
```

if the condition is false because the element doesnt exist shouldnt it execute the else statement? why is it failing on the if conditional and terminating the program?

Comment: it's not _false because the element doesn't exist_. but the method throws an exception. that's the program telling you: "hey! i failed in an _exceptional_ way - you need to catch and handle this edge case"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html

As defined in the documentation, this is thrown when you try to find an element that's not there

> Thrown by WebDriver.findElement(By by) and WebElement.findElement(By by).

Selenium assumes that since you are searching for it, then it must exist. When it doesn't, then it assumes that something went horribly wrong and fails with an exception.

In these cases, when you know it's not an exceptional situation, you can catch the exception and assign the boolean value yourself.

```
bool elementExists;

try {
   elementExists = isDisplayed(rowsWithinDrawer);
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
   elementExists = false;
}

if (elementExists) // etc
```

Comment: this was great information and i believe its now doing what I expected thank you